# Is devtmpfs special with respect to namespaces? a permissions problem

Tags: filesystems, mount, devices, namespace

I'm wondering if devtmpfs is special with respect to namespaces.

Here's my system info (using Vagrant for testing)

```
vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:~/test$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu-xenial 4.4.0-135-generic #161-Ubuntu SMP Mon Aug 27 10:45:01 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

A basic demonstration explains best:

```
vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:~/test$ unshare --ipc --uts --user --mount --fork --pid --net --map-root-user
root@ubuntu-xenial:~/test# mkdir proc
root@ubuntu-xenial:~/test# mkdir sys
root@ubuntu-xenial:~/test# mount -t proc proc ./proc/
root@ubuntu-xenial:~/test# mount -t sysfs sysfs ./sys/
root@ubuntu-xenial:~/test# mkdir dev
root@ubuntu-xenial:~/test# mount -t devtmpfs devtmpfs ./dev/
mount: permission denied
root@ubuntu-xenial:~/test# exit
logout
```

I have the rights to mount proc and sys, but not a devtmpfs?

A tmpfs works, though (also run with the same unshare command)

```
root@ubuntu-xenial:~/test# mount -t tmpfs tmpfs ./dev/
```

EDIT2: Moved previous edit to an answer based on sourcejedi's feedback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it is related to the file system flag `FS_USERNS_MOUNT` (https://lwn.net/Articles/652468/).

A quick grep of the kernel seems to indicate it's not set for `devtmpfs`: [livegrep.com results](https://livegrep.com/search/linux?q=FS_USERNS_MOUNT&fold_case=auto&regex=false&context=true)

If someone has a better answer I'd be happy to accept it instead!