# Why unshare with chroot does not isolate /dev like /proc?

Tags: linux, mount, chroot, unshare

I am following [Container from scratch by Kevin Boone](https://kevinboone.me/containerfromscratch_toc.html)

I have alpine mini root filesystem under /mnt/container/

I am a little puzzled about how the mount works with chroot and unshare involved.

Without unshare if we do

```
chroot /mnt/container /bin/sh -l
```

we get a container(kind of) with its "/" (root) at host machine's `/mnt/container`.

Inside the container if we run the following command;

```
mount -t proc proc /proc >& /dev/null
mount -t devtmpfs dev /dev/ >& /dev/null
```

we see that we have mounted the host system's /proc and /dev and hence we can see the processes that are running on the host with `ps -ef` and can create a file in /dev as well which will be created on the host. This is expected because there is still no namespace isolation.

To create the namespace isolation we do;

```
unshare -mpfu chroot /mnt/container /bin/sh -l
```

and then inside the container we run

```
mount -t proc proc /proc >& /dev/null
mount -t devtmpfs dev /dev/ >& /dev/null
```

This time `ps -ef` will show only two processes that are inside the container. What I understand(correct me if I am wrong) is that `mount -t proc proc /proc >& /dev/null` did not mount the /proc of host system, but created a new directory /proc of type procfs, hence Isolation.

But, and this is the question,
/dev inside the container is still the same /dev of the host. I can still create files inside /dev and it shows up on host machine.

Why is /dev not isolated like /proc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`devtmpfs` isn’t namespaced (see [its `shmem`-based context initialisation](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.18.14/source/mm/shmem.c#L3863)), and it’s also not intended for use inside user namespaces (see [Is devtmpfs special with respect to namespaces? a permissions problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/469263/86440)).

There have been attempts to change this, for example [this 2014 patch series submitted by Seth Forshee](https://lkml.kernel.org/lkml/CALCETrWbtoQsp4wyD6CJ66Yh0UF_gDoT5U_CT2qD6+87PnnjZw@mail.gmail.com/T/#mf15c9650a2afb72603a49830678b435bc24615ca). But the kernel maintainers, Greg KH in particular, are of the opinion that sharing a `devtmpfs` instance between the host and user namespaces, even a namespace-aware instance, [isn’t useful](https://lkml.kernel.org/lkml/CALCETrWbtoQsp4wyD6CJ66Yh0UF_gDoT5U_CT2qD6+87PnnjZw@mail.gmail.com/T/#m4110d7d9ee8db7bc9c9f60330e5aa8296c35dcbc):

> > Splitting a namespaced devtmpfs from loopdevfs discussion might be
> > sensible.  However, in defense of a namespaced devtmpfs I'd say
> > that for userspace to, at every container startup, bind-mount in
> > devices from the global devtmpfs into a private tmpfs (for systemd's
> > sake it can't just be on the container rootfs), seems like something
> > worth avoiding.
>
> I think having to pick and choose what device nodes you want in a
> container is a good thing.  Becides, you would have to do the same
> thing in the kernel anyway, what's wrong with userspace making the
> decision here, especially as it knows exactly what it wants to do much
> more so than the kernel ever can.

Basically, if you need `/dev` inside your user namespace, you should populate it manually.

[How does /proc interact with PID namespaces?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/707212/86440) explains the `/proc` behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Kevin Boone's container techniques do not amount to the kind of contenerization possible by Docker or Virtual Machines.

On Linux /dev and /proc are not file system directories. They are o/s special entities that just happen to be reachable as file system like objects.

Many commands require inspecting the contents of those entities.

Directories named "dev" and "proc" can be created anywhere, but they may probably only look like "overalys" to the real /dev and /proc pseudo-filesystem dirs.

Comment: Welcome to Unix. This answer could be improved by explaining why /dev is all of the normal files, yet /proc is containerize to only things relevant to the container.